# Hide tab bar in view with push has a slight delay

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, uitabbar

I am trying to hide the tab bar during the push to `UserProfileViewController` from a viewcontroller that has tabBar underneath.

code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  guard let toVC = UIStoryboard(name:"UserProfile", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userProfileVC") as? ProfileViewController else { return }

  ...

  toVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(toVC, animated: true)
}
```

so the code works fine and it does hide the bottom bar on push. However, right after the push, it gives me a slight delay and shows a blank white space underneath because of the hidden tab bar for like a second or two. I want to get rid of the bottom white space on push. Please help.

I have already tried:

- ticking `Hide Bottom Bar On Push` in storyboard
- ticking `Under Opaque Bars On Push` in storyboard

Layouts & Extend Edges options ticked in storyboard:

- Adjust Scroll View Insets
- Hides Bottom Bar On Push
- Under Top Bars
- Under Bottom Bars
- Under Opaque Bars

Comment: One possibility for the delay is the time required to load the storyboard. There are different things you could do but the simplest is hiding the nav bar before loading the storyboard: self.navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated. If the guard to load the nav bar fails (should never happen) you can setNavigationBarHidden to false.

Comment: Norman, thanks for the reply, but I am having trouble with the tab bar. Why would it help me by hiding the nav bar?

Comment: Apologies, self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

Comment: Perfect, works like charm thanks a lot.